# Redirect after login depending on the URL

Tags: php, customization, login

I am having issue with this part of my function:
The idea here is to set the URL to `?login=true` if the user logs in via `wp-login.php`. But if the user visits a restricted front end page which contains `?redirect_to=` in the URL they should be redirected after the login.
But for some reason this doesn't work. I always end up in the dashboard with `?login=true` in the URL even if I login on a page which contains `?redirect_to`

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function( $url, $query, $user ) {
  $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
  if (isset($_GET['redirect_to']) && trim($_GET['redirect_to']) != '') {
    return $url;
  }
  else {
    return get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) .  'wp-admin/index.php?login=true';
  }
}, 10, 3);

add_action('current_screen', function ( $user ) {
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($userID);
    if ($_GET['login'] == true && $user_info->primary_blog) {
        $primary_url = get_blogaddress_by_id($user_info->primary_blog) . 'wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=visitor';
        $site_id = $user_info->primary_blog;
        if (!current_user_can_for_blog($site_id, 'create_users')) {
          wp_redirect( $primary_url );
          exit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: check this document https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Comment: Yes, I am aware how the redirect work. And I am able to make it work, but for some reason the code above are only redirecting to the dashboard. Check the updated question with the complete code.